# Any way to avoid git checkout -f "warning directory is not empty"?

Tags: git, git-checkout, git-clean

I have a git repository that contains multiple branch that diverged a lot. When I say diverged it means that each branch can contain new folder or submodule and a lot of diffs between files.

When you checkout a branch that doesn't have the same submodule you initiated with git submodule update --init in your current branch you can fall into this kind of issue:

```
 error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout
     path_to_submodule/my_file.txt
     path_to_submodule/second_file.txt
     ...
```

To overcome this issue I'm using:

```
git checkout -f my_branch
```

This way "git proceed even if the index or the working tree differs from HEAD, and even if there are untracked files in the way" (from the doc)

But when I do this I have a lot of warning saying that git cannot remove not empty directory..

```
warning: cannot remove my_directory. Directory not empty
```

As it's a warning we can ignore it but then when you do a git status you have all those directories that are untracked. So to clean them I use:

```
git clean -xdff
```

My goal is to have a clean environment switching between two branches. That is why I'm using git clean. I know all the consequences using this command.

When you have a lot of submodules the logs can be quite messy with all those warnings when you force switch a branch. So I was wondering if there is a better way of doing that ? I have not seen any options in git checkout to automatically remove the untracked files/submodules when --force is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So I was wondering if there is a better way of doing that ?

This is where I consider [`git worktree`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree) (that I [present here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30185564/6309))

Having two different folders, representing each two different checked out branches, avoids all this "overwritten/clean" messy business when trying to switch from one branch to another.

And you only clone the repository once.

Comment: Thanks, I will check that out! It's for a CI/CV automation process so I will have to dig into this a little bit to put that in place

Comment: @CyDevos If you CI/CD process relied on *one* path, I usually use a symlink as part of that fixed path. And I change the symlink to point to `branch1` folder or `branch2` folder, depending on what I need.